# Changing C++ compiler version on VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compilation

I am new to C++, having just a bit of programming experience in Python.
On setting C++ up in VSCode, I have installed C/C++ by Microsoft, C/C++ Extension Pack and also Code Runner by Jun Han. These choices, especially the latter, were made based on some Youtube videos I watched.

Upon trying to Initialize with the curly brackets, I realised the code wouldn't compile. I ran a check compiler program and found out the compiler's version is C++98. I want to change to a more recent version which supports the newer features.

That said, how exactly do I change a compiler version, and which one do you recommend? Is C++11 already outdated?

I tried looking it up, and I think the line `code-runner.executorMap` could be useful, but I don't really know how to use it. Is there a way to do it in Settings or will I have to change it through the Terminal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My advice is to uninstall MinGW start over and follow the official VSCode instructions on how to setup MinGW using msys2: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) That compiler will be gcc-12.2 and default in c++17 I believe.

Comment: What platform are you running vscode on? Which compiler have you installed? I don't recommend using code runner, it'll soon start getting in your way if you do anything more complicated than using a single file. Use a proper c++ build system like cmake (which has a vscode plugin that makes using c++ much easier)

Answer (score 2):

I will try to help you step by step :

1. Uninstall `MinGW` from your pc
2. Install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) from here (Window 8.1 or newer)
3. Check the option : `"Run MSYS2 now"` and open the shell
4. Digit : `pacman -Syu` to update packets
5. Open the pink app : `MSYS2 MSYS` by browsing it from the search bar of Windows
6. Digit `pacman -Su` to update it too
7. Exit and now open the `blue app` called : `MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit`
8. In the shell in ordere to install the `compiler` digit : `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`
   (64 Bit System)
   `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-gcc`
   (32 Bit System)
9. Now for the `debugger` :
   (64 bit)
   `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb`
   (32 bit)
   `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-gdb`
10. From the `command prompt` of Windows digit these 3 commands to check that everything was installed correctly :

`gcc --version`

`g++ --version`

`gdb --version`

11. Go to [this website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) and go to the `step number 6` to configure the `Path` of mingw (if you installed 64-bit) :
12. Now because you have already installed `C/C++ extension` , create a new folder containing your source file, `(VERY IMPORTANT because a file won't compile if it's not into a folder ! )` and from the `"Terminal"` section of VScode select : `"Configure Default Build Task"` while selecting a c++ file and click : `"C/C++ : gcc.exe build active file"`
13. A folder called `.vscode` will show up containing the file :  `tasks.json`, that is used for telling the compiler all the parameters in order to compile your code.
14. I recommend to use Powershell as default terminal if you want to set it then press `CTRL + SHIFT + P` and search for `"Terminal: Select Default Profile"` and select powershell.
15. From the  `"Run"` section select "`Run Without Debugging"` Or `"Start debugging"` and you are good to go ! Just check the terminal in the bottom section of vscode for the output of your code ! Hope it helps!

Comment: Your 64/32 bit labels are inconsistent (with regard to where they appear in relation to the package name), and after updating your PATH in Windows you need to reboot. I wouldn't recommend repeating official documentation here, unless you intend to maintain this answer if/when the official documentation makes changes. Better to just refer OP to the source.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question to suggest tuyere using mingw or even Windows?

Comment: @sweenish I know that 64/32 Bit instructions are not very clear but I just wanted to show that there is not a single command for everyone, and I was supposing that he has a 64-Bit machine, plus you are right when you say that It would have been better to just refer to the official documentation but sometimes I find them hard to understand and I preferred to help as much as I can. Ty for the comment

Comment: @AlanBirtles what do you mean by that?

Comment: Lvcaa and @AlanBirtles, thank you for the contributions! I have a Macbook, I forgot to mention it. Would the instructions be similar?

Comment: @imarqs you have to follow this procedure [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac), the compiler will be Clang instead of gcc and gdb, I think that this documentation is far more simple than the windows one so I hope you manage to configure everything correctly, I can't help you that much because I never touched MacOS and I've always used Windows as my OS.